# MariaDB - Strategy to improve performance in a table with more than 100 million data

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

I have a table that stores user data and it currently has over 100 million pieces of data.

As this table has a large amount of data, queries involving a date range are very slow. In this table, for example, there is a birth column of type date and we do many things in it, as in the example:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE YEAR(CURDATE() - YEAR(birth) > 15
```

To improve the performance of these queries I thought of partitioning this table into 93 partitions considering the year.

I thought about partitioning, for example, a list like this:

```
ALTER TABLE USERS
PARTITION BY range(year(birth))(
PARITTION p_year_1930 VALUES LESS THAN (1930),
PARITTION p_year_1931 VALUES LESS THAN (1931),
...
PARITTION p_year_1930 VALUES LESS THAN (2023),
)
```

or using hash:

```
PARTITION BY hash(year(birth))(
partitions 93
)
```

My question is whether partitioning would be a good strategy in this situation or if there would be another better solution using indexed keys for example and if there is a difference between using hash or range in terms of performance in this case considering queries with this where clause: `YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birth) > 15`

@EDIT

As requested by @Schwern, structure of my table:

```
client_inss_dados | CREATE TABLE `client_inss_dados` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SSN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEX` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BIRTH` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WAGE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COD_BANK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PHONE_01` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_SSN` (`SSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci
```

`SELECT VERSION();`

`10.5.19-MariaDB`

Comment: Please show us the schema and indexes for your user table. You might do well with an index on `birth` and one on `year(birth)`.

Comment: Coincidentally improvements in MariaDB on this sort of query ([MDEV-8320](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8320) are [in progress](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/410e0c42db3bcb1fcd811490bd5297d3a4cb967c) at this time. Partitioning won't help.

Comment: Please add the result of `SELECT VERSION();` to your question.

Comment: Your example search predicate `YEAR(CURDATE() - YEAR(birth) > 15` isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) -- it can't exploit an index. Read about that.  Dan's suggestion will give you a way to run that query that is sargable.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Thanks! I added the version in my question

Comment: In future questions, please identify up front that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed since then. They are no longer compatible, and depending on the question, a solution for one does not necessarily work for the other.

Answer (score 2):

As @Schwern indicated, create a column of the year of birth. This can be a [generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/).

```
ALTER TABLE client_inss_dados
ADD yr INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(birth)) STORED,
ADD INDEX yr_index (yr)
```

The general principle to get a index used is for it to be an exposed value not surrounded by an expression in SQL. So:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE yr < YEAR(CURDATE()) - 15
```

Use `EXPLAIN {query}` to see if the index `yr_index` was used.

The [MariaDB-11.1 preview](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-11-1-0-preview-release-now-available/) just came out with a few feature to simplify the `YEAR` function applied to a column to use an index on a `date`/`datetime`/`timestamp` column.

So the first step is to store `BIRTH` as a `date` type and create an index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE client_inss_dados
MODIFY BIRTH date
, ADD INDEX (BIRTH)
```

As this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ld3lnFHc) shows, the BIRTH in the right date format will convert.

With the MariaDB-11.1 preview feature, only a small rearrangement of your query will be required (complex rearrangement of maths expressions/relations to match an index isn't implemented in MariaDB).

```
SELECT * FROM client_inss_dados WHERE YEAR(BIRTH) < YEAR(CURDATE()) - 15
```

If no major issues are found with this implementation during the preview phase, future 11.1 and later releases will have this feature. Check the fixed version of [MDEV-8320](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8320) once the 11.1 preview is over to examine if it got included.

Comment: You can skip the generated column and directly index `year(birth)`.

Comment: @Schwern You can do that in MySQL 8.0, but in MySQL 5.7 they have not yet implemented expression indexes, so one would have to create the generated column first. The OP has not answered which version they are using.